# How to check if value from a field in a table object is equal to specific string in django template language?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am iterating over all the entries in a django table called `Ideas.` One field in the table is `status`, and I want to check if the status is equal to some specific string. I have already checked that I am accessing this field correctly, with `idea.status` in my case, but I can't find how to compare that entry to a specific string in the django template language docs. I am trying to change a table's cell color based on what is in that cell. Here is what I tried, but to no avail:

```
{% for idea in ideas_list %}
...
        {% if idea.status == 'Not Started' %}
        <td style="background-color:red;">
        {% elif idea.status == 'Completed' %}
        <td style="background-color:green;">
        {% elif idea.status == 'In Progress' %}
        <td style="background-color:yellow;">
        {% else %}
        <td>
        {% endif %}
            {{idea.status}} &nbsp;</td>
...
{% endfor %}
```

My page is still rendering with the status text in the table, suggesting to me that all the if's were failed, which would end in the else condition being met, giving `<td>{{idea.status}} &nbsp;</td>`, with no cell color, and suggesting to me the problem is in my if statements themselves.

Comment: The syntax looks correct. The `idea.status` values may not match correctly (casing, whitespace). Print the status on the page to confirm (be sure to check the page source).

Comment: It must be related to what you said. I tried `{% if idea.status != 'Not Started' %}` etc, and the cells turned red, so the error is in the evaluation of the if statement somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer that worked, and indicates that it has something to do with the string formatting that djnago is using. I used the slugify filter, which converts strings to a specific format (lowercase, dashes instead of spaces), and then change my if conditions to match that format, and it worked.

```
{% for idea in ideas_list %}
...
        <td>{{idea.priority}} &nbsp;</td>
        <td>{{idea.difficulty}} &nbsp;</td>
        {% if idea.status|slugify == 'not-started' %}
        <td style="background-color:red;">
        {% elif idea.status|slugify  == 'completed' %}
        <td style="background-color:green;">
        {% elif idea.status|slugify  == 'in-progress' %}
        <td style="background-color:yellow;">
        {% else %}
        <td>
        {% endif %}
            {{idea.status}} &nbsp;</td>
...
{% endfor %}
```

You can see how django formats strings with slugify here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/

Answer (score 0):

Your template part is correct.
This is correct syntax:

```
{% if idea.status == 'Not Started' %}
```

#### Logging data

The simplest way to debug what you have in the template log what you have before rendering the template. You can use the logging module [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/logging/) or simple:

```
print(payload_for_rendering)
```

#### Django Debug Toolbar

Install the main debug tool for every Django developer - [Django Debug Toolbar install docs](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html). You can use the module "Template" in the toolbar to see the data that your template received in the nice user interface. You can check that you're sending correct data to the template render.